# create domain from header to detail in odoo 10 using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

i dunno what's wrong with my code. I have two model, one is payroll.adjustment that i used model in my xml and one is payroll.adjustment.lines.  All i need to do is to create a domain in a field on payroll.adjustment.lines which is employee_id and here what i do.

```
<field name="employee_id" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="
[('address_id','=',company_id)]"/>
```

but it shows an error "Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'company_id' is not defined"

My code in .py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError

class PayrollAdjustment(models.Model):
    _name = 'payroll.adjustment'
    _description ='Payroll Adjustment'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", related='doc_num')
    doc_num = fields.Char(string="Document No.")
    state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'),
                          ('confirm', 'Waiting for Approval'),
                          ('approved','Approved'),
                          ('void', 'Void')],default='draft')
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Company",domain="
    [('is_company','=',True)]")
    date_from = fields.Date(string="Date From", required= True)
    date_to = fields.Date(string="Date To", required= True)
    adjustment_lines = 
    fields.One2many('payroll.adjustment.lines','adj_id',string="Adjustment 
    lines")
    color = fields.Integer()
    sample = fields.Many2one ('hr.employee')

    @api.multi
    def action_draft(self):
        self.state = 'draft'

    @api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):
        self.state = 'confirm'

    @api.multi
    def action_approve(self):
        self.state = 'approved'

    @api.multi
    def action_void(self):
        self.state = 'void'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('payroll.adj.seq')

        return super(PayrollAdjustment, self).create(vals)

class PayrollAdjustmentLines(models.Model):
    _name = 'payroll.adjustment.lines'
    _description = 'Payroll Adjustment Lines'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']

    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',    
    string="Employee",required=True)
    adjustment_for = fields.Many2one('hr.salary.rule', string="Adjustment 
    for",domain=[('appears_on_adj', '=', True)], required=True)
    remarks = fields.Char(string="Remarks")
    amount = fields.Float(string="Amount", default = 0.00)
    adj_id = fields.Many2one('payroll.adjustment',string="Payroll 
    Adjustment",ondelete='cascade')
```

my code .xml

```
<record id="payroll_adjustment_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">payroll_adjustment.form</field>
        <field name="model">payroll.adjustment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                 <header>
                    <button name="action_draft" type="object" string="Set 
back to draft" states="confirm"/>
                    <button name="action_confirm" type="object" 
string="Confirm" states="draft" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="action_approve" type="object" 
string="Approve" states="confirm" class="oe_highlight" 
groups="hr_payroll.group_hr_payroll_manager"/>
                    <button name="action_void" type="object" string="Void" 
states="confirm,approved" class="oe_highlight" 
groups="hr_payroll.group_hr_payroll_manager"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
                 </header>
                <sheet>
                     <div class="pull-left">
                        <label for="doc_num" class="oe_edit_only oe_inline"/>
                        <h1>
                            <field name="doc_num" readonly="1"/>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <label for="company_id"/>
                        <div>
                            <field name="company_id" class="oe_inline" 
attrs="{'readonly': [('state','not in',('draft'))]}"/>
                        </div>

                       <label for="date_from" string="Period"/>
                        <div>
                            <field name="date_from" class="oe_inline" 
attrs="{'readonly': [('state','not in',('draft'))]}"/> -
                            <field name="date_to" class="oe_inline" attrs="
{'readonly': [('state','not in',('draft'))]}"/>
                            <field name="sample" domain="
[('address_id','=',company_id)]"/>
                        </div>
                    </group>
                    <field name="adjustment_lines" attrs="{'readonly': 
[('state','not in',('draft'))]}" context="{'company': company_id }">
                        <tree editable="1">
                            <field name="employee_id" options="{'no_create': 
True}" domain="[('address_id','=',company_id)]"/>
                            <field name="adjustment_for" options="
{'no_create': True}"/>
                            <field name="amount"/>
                            <field name="remarks"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding domain in field employee_id of 'payroll.adjustment.lines' model, but 'company_id' field is not in that model but it is in parent model 'payroll.adjustment'.

So you should write as following :

```
<field name="employee_id" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="
[('address_id','=',parent.company_id)]"/>
```

Comment: hello sir/ma'am. Is it possible if i want to display the employee_id on the tree view in payroll.adjustment? What can i add? is it correct? <field name="child.employee_id"/>?